# How to add dynamic dependency between two entity reference fields in content creation form?

Tags: forms, ajax

I want to create a dependency between two Entity Reference (ER) fields, one towards content and the other towards vocabulary terms.

My first content type A has an ER field (A1) to a vocabulary (V1) with multiple possible values.

My second content type B has a first field ER (B1) to the content type A which must then condition the options of a second field ER (B2) to the vocabulary V1 by proposing in its widget only the authorized values, entered in the field A1.

I first tested with a classic View Entity Reference List but the dynamic dimension linked to the value chosen in field B1 is missing.

I then tested with the [Dependent Fields](https://www.drupal.org/project/dependent_fields) module which seems to correspond perfectly to the problem.

But when I finally managed to build something, I only see one choice offered in field B2 when I should have several (in my example of node A created) and I have configured the Views field by breaking down the terms (one per row of View) since it is a multi-valued field.

When I test the preview in Views by indicating the ID of content type A as an argument, I obtain the authorized terms of the V1 vocabulary.

Is my system poorly designed? How would you have gone about creating this dynamic dependency in content creation form B?

Thanks for any tip here.